# Rendering JSON data in react native

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native

I'm currently using my api to render all posts in JSON to react native. But I keep getting this undefined error. And sometimes the data just wont render. Can anyone give me any help on rendering this data in react native? And explain to me what i'm doing wrong? I'm pretty new with JSON. Thanks :)

Here is my JSON:

```
{"data":[{"id":"1","type":"posts","links":{"self":"https://example.com/posts/1"},"attributes":{"title":"Laughter Post","context":{}},"relationships":{"user":{"links":{"self":"https://example.com/posts/1/relationships/user","related":"https://example.com/posts/1/user"}}}}]}
```

And here is my react native code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
state = {
data: []
};

componentWillMount() {
this.fetchData();
}

fetchData = async () => {
const response = await fetch("https://example.com/posts.json");
const json = await response.json();
this.setState({ data: json.data });
};

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={item => item.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <Text>
          {`${item.title}`}
        </Text>}
       />
    </View>
   );
  }
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 marginTop: 15,
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: "center",
 alignItems: "center",
 backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are accessing `title` directly from the root, but it is inside key `attributes`

It should be

```
{`${item. attributes.title}`}
```

Or else if you can tell us the exact error, we can help you more regarding this issue.

Comment: Wow I spent most of my day trying to figure this out. I feel quite stupid. It Worked! thank you so much!